# Issues with javascript code, JSON request from Github

Tags: javascript, html, json

I'm having an issue getting this to work. 
I'm still very new to JS and learning the syntax. I'm attempting to modify someone's script that was built to return **ALL** the repositories in a github-repository (which, unmodified works fine). 
I'm attempting to modify it to return only the repositories with a specified primary language, i.e. 'Matlab'. I've probably royally butchered it by now.

```
 $(function () {
 var lang = 'Matlab';
 var lang2 = '#' + lang;
 $('#' + lang).html('Loading...');

 var username = 'lallers';
 var requri = 'https://api.github.com/users/' + username;
 var repouri = 'https://api.github.com/users/' + username + '/repos';
 requestJSON(requri, function (json) {
     var fullname = json.name;
     var username = json.login;
     var aviurl = json.avatar_url;
     var profileurl = json.html_url;
     var location = json.location;
     var followersnum = json.followers;
     var followingnum = json.following;
     var reposnum = json.public_repos;
     var email = json.email;
     if (fullname == undefined) {
         fullname = username;
     }
     var outhtml = '<div class="repolist clearfix"><ul>';

     var repositories;
     $.getJSON(repouri, function (json) {
         repositories = json;
         outputPageContent();
     });

     function outputPageContent() {
         if (repositories.length == 0) {
             outhtml = outhtml + '<p>No repos!</p></div>';
         } else {
             $.each(repositories, function (index) {
                 if (repositories[index].language == lang) {
                     outhtml = outhtml + '<li><a href="' + repositories[index].html_url + '" target="_blank">' + repositories[index].name + '</a></li>';
                 } else {
                     return true;
                 }
             }); // end each statement
             outhtml = outhtml + '</ul></div>';
         } // end else statement
         $('#' + lang).html(outhtml);
     } // end else statement

 }); // end requestJSON Ajax call

 function requestJSON(url, callback) {
     $.ajax({
         url: url,
         complete: function (xhr) {
             callback.call(null, xhr.responseJSON);
         }
     });
 }
});
```

Comment: `glang` contains the jQuery object. I don't understand the way you're using it in your code.

Comment: Where do you set the language that you're trying to search for? It looks like you're using the `glang` variable for that as well.

Comment: @Barmar If i'm honest, i'm not sure how to do any of this in general. I come from using Matlab and am learning this on my own. What I was attempting to do with the `glang` term is use it as the parameter that I search for (as you asked in the second question). This script should run, find all the repos with their language = `glang` and return them back to the div element that i've labelled on the page with id = `glang`, i.e. I've made a `<div id="Matlab">` then the script runs and puts the output in that div element.

Comment: How are you passing that parameter to the function? `$(function()...)` is shorthand for `$(document).ready(function() ...)`, and the parameter it receives is the `jQuery` object, not anything from the DOM. If you have DIVs named after the languages, you probably should be writing a click handler on those DIVs, and get the parameter from the ID.

Comment: Something like `<div class="lang" id="Matlab">`. Then you write `$(".lang").click(function() { lang = this.id; ... })`

Comment: I ended up figuring it out for a specific case, as in calling the script with 'Matlab' already defined. I updated the code to reflect it working correctly. How do I convert this to a general case so that i can put it in a .js file and call it with 'Matlab' defined as a parameter?

Comment: Define a named function that takes the language name as a parameter, then call that function.